# MySQL server reporting correct start-up but return errors on connection attempt

Tags: mysql, wamp

I'm trying to set up my local development environment, to which i'm using the ever so easy to install "WAMP" package.

Now i install wamp, run it and start all services, i try connecting to the MySQL server, but i get an error:

```
SQL Error (2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10060)
```

It doesn't matter if i try it via a SQL client or PHP, and i've tried re-installing a few times.

So i decided to take a look at the mysql.log file after a startup, and this is what i get:

```
111024 22:57:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111024 22:57:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
111024 22:57:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
111024 22:57:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
111024 22:57:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
111024 22:57:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111024 22:57:41 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
111024 22:57:41  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
111024 22:57:42 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
111024 22:57:42 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
111024 22:57:42 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.16-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

The second to last line reading "wampmysqld ready for connections." indicates it should work, which confuses me...

I have close to no idea what's wrong, so i hope you guys have any suggestions for what i can try to do in order to get this up and running.

Comment: Check if _"some program"_ is listening to port 3306 on your pc using (just an example) `netstat -a`

Comment: When the MySQL server is started, this returns a row saying "TCP    0.0.0.0:3306    MyPcName:0    LISTENING", but if i shut down the MySQL server nothing is returned about port 3306...

Comment: OK, this means that MSql is starting and listening to that port (correct). Try (from command line) `mysql -u root -p` and see if you're able to connect...

Comment: This returns the error as stated above: http://imgur.com/gxonB

Comment: OK, try to connect to your pc from another one in the same network using `mysql -h your_network_ip -u root -p`

Comment: Returns exact same error. (Except my ip shown instead of 'localhost')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i have been troubled with this for quite some time, but i believe I've found a solution now.

I've done everything from deleting everything i could find containing "mysql" from files to the registry database, even so nothing helped.

I even ended up using a Virtual Machine as a temporary solution, but as it changed IP i had to edit the `my.cnf`, which is where i realized my `my.ini` missed the `bind-address` value.

**The solution** turned out to be annoyingly simple, even though i'm not sure exactly what did it.

Anyway, i ended up editing some things in the `my.ini`, i edited these rows:

```
[client]
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

[wampmysqld]
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

I commented out the `log-bin` line, edited the `socket` lines and added `bind-address` so it looked like this:

```
[client]
socket      = C:/wamp/mysql.sock

[wampmysqld]
socket      = C:/wamp/mysql.sock
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

#log-bin=mysql-bin
```

As i said, not sure what did it, but if you have the same problems for some reason, some of this might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, "localhost" doesn't resolve locally by default.

Assuming (big assumption!) you're using Windows 7, you'll need to do one of two things:

- either use `mysql -h hostname -u root -p` (using your own hostname) so it resolves the host properly
- ...or uncomment the line containing `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)

The second option will allow the default host "localhost" to be used when you do `mysql -u root -p` without specifying a hostname.

Comment: Opening my "hosts" file i see four lines saying "127.0.0.1 localhost". Besides, i cant connect with 127.0.0.1 either or externally.